# How to get a PipelineComponent for IDTSComponentMetadata100

Tags: ssis

I'm writing a UI editor for an SSIS custom pipeline component.

When BIDS invokes the editor, it passes a IDTSComponentMetadata100 instance to the editor. How do I get a reference to my (managed) PipelineComponent derived instance?

Comment: ManagedComponentHost.InnerObject will return the PipelineComponent... does anyone know how to get hold of the ManageComponentHost, or anything that returns a IDTSManagedComponent100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you want to do something like this:

```
void Initialize(
    IDTSComponentMetaData100 dtsComponentMetadata,
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider
){
    IDtsPipelineEnvironmentService pipelineService = (IDtsPipelineEnvironmentService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IDtsPipelineEnvironmentService));
    IDTSPipeline100 mainPipe = pipelineService.Pipeline;
    // access mainPipe.PathCollection etc
    TaskHost pipelineTaskHost = pipelineService.PipelineTaskHost;
    MainPipe mainPipe2 = pipelineTaskHost.InnerObject as MainPipe;
    // that is less direct but should work too
}
```

You can do other interesting things with the serviceProvider, like inspecting the package's connections or variables, by passing a different type to GetService. See [SQL2008R2 BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522608.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the route via the pipeline service, but my custom data flow components (developed in C#) were not in the IDTSPipeline100.PathCollection - the standard Microsoft ones were.

Digging a bit deeper, I tried getting mainPipe.GetObjectByID(componentID) which works, but it returns a COM object not a C#/Managed object. Attempting to cast throws a "you can't cast from COM to C#Managed" exception.

I can't confirm, but strongly suspect that my C#/Managed custom components don't show up in the PathCollection as they are C#/Managed component vs. COM.